# Why Guard (rspec) stops working on jruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby, guard, specifications

I can't get Guard working on jruby. I have jruby inistalled via rvm next to 1.9.3. Tried to run Guard on 1.9.3 - works fine. How can I make it run spec automatically on every change in `spec` or `lib`?

This is what I get after running `bundle exec guard` and with no files changed in the meantime

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/sample$ bundle exec guard
21:16:46 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
21:16:47 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
21:16:47 - INFO - Running all specs
...

Finished in 0.025 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures

21:17:20 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/vagrant/sample'
before_session hook failed: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /vagrant/sample
org/jruby/RubyFile.java:333:in `initialize'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
[1] guard(main)>
```

And the only way to run spec again is to press ENTER here. Also I can't identify the source of this `No such file or directory` thing (it doesn't pop up on 1.9.3 MRI). I'm not familiar with guard internals and can't really find why that happens.

My `Guardfile` is standard one:

```
guard 'rspec' do        
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
end
```

and `Gemfile` contains only:

```
gem 'rspec', '~>2.13.0'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'rb-inotify', '~>0.9'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `before_session` hook is from [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), but Guard doesn't use this type of hook (we use only :when_started and :after_eval):

```
[1] guard(main)> Pry.hooks
=> #<Pry::Hooks:0x007ff0359a36c0
 @errors=[],
 @hooks=
  {:before_session=>
    [[:default,
      #<Proc:0x007ff0359a3648@/Users/michi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.9.12/lib/pry.rb:11>]],
   :when_started=>
    [[:load_guard_rc,
      #<Proc:0x007ff037a12910@/Users/michi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/interactor.rb:109>]],
   :after_eval=>
    [[:restore_visibility,
      #<Proc:0x007ff037a126e0@/Users/michi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/interactor.rb:116>]],
   :after_session=>[],
   :after_read=>[],
   :before_eval=>[]}>
```

I'd file a Pry bug and run Guard without interactor (`guard -i`) until fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your Guardfile

```
# disable Pry for continious integration
interactor :off
```